# Querying page title to get category posts

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress I am struggling to do a check on the page title and then output posts that match the page title category I have set.

So for example is the page title is 'birmingham' I also have a category named 'birmingham' if both match and then output the post.

Here is my code and for the life of me I have googled it and tried so many things but I am clearly missing something very obvious.

```
      <?php 
      // the query

      $thetitle = get_the_title();

      $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => '$page_title' ) ); ?>


      <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

      <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
      <?php the_post_thumbnail( array( 1000, 315) ) ?></a>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

      <?php else : ?>
      <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`category_name` is misleading. It expect not the real category name but category slug. So if your page title is "foo bar", you are providing this to query while it expects "foo-bar".

To change title into slug, use [`sanitize_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title)

```
$thetitle = sanitize_title(get_the_title());
```

Comment: that worked like a charm , I was very close! thank you.